# Launch a follow-up action in R

Tags: r, rstudio

Is it possible to run a code, let's say one row of code (in RStudio by pressing Ctrl & Enter) and afterwards to get this row commented out automatically?

Thank for any inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this shold be possible. `rstudioapi` offers all the functionality you need. The code below does exactly what you want, I guess:

```
context <- rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()
rstudioapi::sendToConsole(context$selection[[1]]$text, execute = TRUE)
rstudioapi::insertText(paste0("# ", context$selection[[1]]$text))
```

To perform this with a specific shortcut, you would have to define your own RStudio shortcut. Check out this article of how to do this:

https://www.statworx.com/de/blog/defining-your-own-shortcut-in-rstudio/ 
(full disclosure: I am the author)

Comment: added the code on the bottom of an outsourced function. load the function in the mainscript will result to get "#" in the console but not in the main-script.

Comment: yes, you would have to wrap the functionality above in a proper shortcut. Then you can mark a line, execute the shortcut, and the result is as expected. 
To include the same behavior in the function itself is much more complex, because you would have let the function you call know, which line should be commented out etc. Such document contexts are nasty beasts^^

Comment: Went through. For somebody who has never created an addin, it is a hard piece of work. Some important information are missing to accomplish all steps properly. Wrote you a message.